# Django unable to load JS and CSS files as static resources

Tags: python, django

I have a `html` file called `base.html` inside a folder called **`html`**. There are two directories at the same level as **`html`** - **`js`** and **`css`** which contain static resources. The `base.html` refers those static resources through relative paths, like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/debounce.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/base.css">
```

It works as expected. Now I copied the entire directory structure to my `django` project. This is how the root folder `ecom` looks like:

[image]

The `customviews` directory contains the **`html`**, **`js`** and **`css`** directories, as well as a `myview.py` file, which is refered to in the `urls.py` file within the `ecom` subdirectory as:

```
from customviews.myview import *
urlpatterns = [url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
               url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
               url(r'^base/', base)]
```

The `base` method in `myviews.py` simply runs as follows:

```
def base(request):
    return render_to_response("base.html")
```

And the relevant part of `settings.py` looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(dirfunc(dirfunc(__file__)), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
                 os.path.join(dirfunc(dirfunc(__file__)), 'customviews/html').replace('\\', '/'),
                 os.path.join(dirfunc(dirfunc(__file__)), 'customviews/js').replace('\\', '/'),
                 os.path.join(dirfunc(dirfunc(__file__)), 'customviews/css').replace('\\', '/')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

When I fire up the server and load `base`, only the basic html is rendered, the `css` and `js` are missing. How do I load both?

Comment: What do your static/media config settings look like?

Comment: Don't have any I guess. I mean, I did not add anything extra to the default files. I did read something about them here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS, but could not understand how to apply them. At the bottom of `settings.py` there seems to be a `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to be including the static resource folders in your template dirs. What you do need to do is set your [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) under settings and include a [`static` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) in your templates are calling those resources.

Comment: So in this case, the dirs list would consist of the full paths to my css and js folders?

Comment: If you have all your static resources in one folder, you can just point to that folder and then include the rest of the path with the static tag. Make sure there are no files in the folder that you wouldn't want public. I would advise putting them in a subdirectory named `static` within ecom and then the static tag would know to look there without you pointing to it.

Comment: No I have multiple folders, like images, css, js which need to be separate for maintenance purpose. And what do I have to do to the way they are being referenced within the HTML? Currently they are referenced as `../js/foo.js` or `../images/test.jpg`. How will those paths change?

Comment: They can still all be in separate folders, just within the same subdirectory. The references in the templates would have to be changed to `"{% static "js/foo.js %}"` or `"{% static "images/test.jpg" %}"`

Comment: So here, for example, all the `css`, `js` and `images` folders are within `customviews`. What should be the value of `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `static` tags, as well as the image path mentioned in the HTML file? Just one note, I am not using any template feature in the HTML file, just raw, dumb HTML for now. Do I still need template tags there?

Comment: You're using `render_to_response("base.html")` `base.html`, therefore, is a template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117022/discussion-between-attitudemonger-and-miyamoto).